# Openshift Minecraft Server timeout

Tags: server, openshift, minecraft

I recently made an Minecraft Server on [Openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) with [this Tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/free-minecraft-cloud-server-hosting/).
After I made the port forwarding, I was able do get a Connection in Minecraft to my Server. But I cannot login! It simply ends with the Message: `Timed-Out`.
In the Server logs I only see, what I know: I lost my connection. Here are the logs:

```
2016-01-01 17:29:17 [INFO] Starting minecraft server version 1.
2016-01-01 17:29:17 [INFO] Loading properties
2016-01-01 17:29:17 [INFO] Default game type: SURVIVAL
2016-01-01 17:29:17 [INFO] Generating keypair
2016-01-01 17:29:18 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on 127.2.1
2016-01-01 17:29:18 [INFO] Preparing level "world"
2016-01-01 17:29:18 [INFO] Preparing start region for level 0
2016-01-01 17:29:20 [INFO] Preparing spawn area: 52%
2016-01-01 17:29:20 [INFO] Done (1.911s)! For help, type "help"
2016-01-01 17:30:41 [SEVERE] Reached end of stream
2016-01-01 17:30:41 [INFO] /127.2.105.129:29361 lost connection
 java.io.IOException: Bad packet id 72
    at ei.a(SourceFile:193)
    at ci.i(SourceFile:250)
    at ci.c(SourceFile:16)
    at cj.run(SourceFile:94)
2016-01-01 18:10:21 [INFO] /127.2.105.129:32075 lost connection
 java.io.IOException: Bad packet id 72
    at ei.a(SourceFile:193)
    at ci.i(SourceFile:250)
    at ci.c(SourceFile:16)
    at cj.run(SourceFile:94)
2016-01-01 18:10:21 [INFO] /127.2.105.129:32098 lost connection
 java.io.IOException: Bad packet id 72
    at ei.a(SourceFile:193)
    at ci.i(SourceFile:250)
    at ci.c(SourceFile:16)
    at cj.run(SourceFile:94)
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with your ports.

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.IOException: Bad packet id 72` deals will a malformed packet. I've read where it could mean anything from not specifying the correct port to trying to connect with incompatible mod versions.

In your case, it looks like you are explicitly defining the `server-ip` in your `server.properties`. In the starting logs:

```
2016-01-01 17:29:18 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on 127.2.1
```

`127.2.1` is not a valid address, so it makes sense to me that packet transmission would be malformed. Leave this field blank (as it is by default) or provide a valid IPv4 address.

I feel pretty confident that is what is going on because the tutorial your provided makes you set this field as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Bad packet id 72` means that you are trying to login to a server that's port isn't configured correctly. in the log, you have mentioned `2016-01-01 17:29:18 [INFO] Starting Minecraft server on 127.2.1.`

solution:
(I have configured my test server to similar to yours)
1. go to server.properties and in `server-ip:`section, remove the content after that.  That will make it the default ip

2. go to your router home page and port forward the server to `25565`
3. it should now work

Good luck on your new server! :)